# LDAP - How to filter users with specific attributes

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

We have an Active Directory but don't have direct access to the machine hosting this AD, so I'm using a Linux box to connect to it.

We are able to successfully login using :

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldapmd.ad.test.com -p 3268 -D "cn=test\, test1,ou=users,ou=Australia,ou=asia,OU=Sites,DC=ad,DC=test,DC=com" -W -b "OU=Access-Groups,OU=OrgResources,DC=ad,DC=test,DC=com"
```

Is there a filter that I could add to get all users with the following attributes :

- Common Name
- email
- sAMAccountName
- Country

Comment: Your question has been answered.  Please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter to grab only users : `(|(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))`

For the attribute list, refer to this mapping :

```
Friendly Name | Attribute Name 
-----------------------------------
Common Name   | cn
email         | mail
Username      | sAMAccountName
Country       | co              (open string value)
Country Name  | c               (ISO-3166 2-digit string value)
Country Code  | countryCode     (ISO-3166 Integer value)
```

So you can try something like (using placeholders for readability) :

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<host>:<port> -D <binddn> -W -b <base> <filter> cn,mail,sAMAccountName,co
```

If you want to grab only users for which some of / all these atributes are set, just extend the filter with a *presence* (`=*`) filter. For example, if email and country are required, the filter string would be :

```
(&(|(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))(mail=*)(co=*))
```

Comment: `-H` expects a URL.